# c++ how to free memory

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, delete-operator

I have the following issue:
I created a data structure to represent a Binary Search Tree using a class called Node. Each Node is connected by pointers to left child and right child.

Trees that will be built are very big (up to 1 milion nodes) so I need a way to free memory after each tree build.

The tree is represented by a pointer to root node:

```
BST_Node *bst = new BST_Node(...);
```

I've tried with `delete bst` and creating a `destructor` `~BST_Node(){delete left; delete right;}` but both of them do not resolve the problem.
The memory usage reaches 99% (8GB) and then I must kill the process to avoid PC restart.

How may I resolve? Thanks

Comment: Variables are **destructed** when they go out of scope, not freed. The `bst` is destructed, but pointers have trivial destructors (perform no action).

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. Use smart pointers. They will automatically clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, this code:

```
BST_Node *bst = new BST_Node(...);
```

should be written:

```
auto bst = std::make_unique<BST_Node>(...);
```

This will create `bst` as a `unique_ptr<BST_Node>` object. The `unique_ptr` is a *smart pointer* class. Smart pointers automatically destroy the underlying object whenever they go out of scope. This frees you from ever having to call delete yourself.

Not only is this type of code easier to write because you don't have to remember to call delete yourself, but it is the *only* way to write code that does not leak memory if an exception gets thrown.

You should use the same `unique_ptr` for the member variables of `BST_Node`.

---

And, unless you're *learning* about binary search trees, you should use the `std::set` class instead of building your own. `std::set` is implemented as a binary search tree (generally, a red-black tree, which is a variant of the binary search tree).

It's also likely that a hash map would be even more efficient than a binary search tree. The hash map in C++ is called `std::unordered_map`.